# Excel difference SUMIF and total SUM (14th digit differs)

Tags: excel-formula

I'm encountering a strange error in Excel.

1. I have 5 cells doing a SUM IF.
2. A 6th cell who gives the total of the 5 SUM IF cells.
3. A conditional format to compare the value in the 6th cells with the total SUM directly in the table (same table as for SUM IF) - If SUM is different from this value then "RED"

On first sight, the values seem the same, but the conditional format is saying that there is a difference.

After checking I can see that the 14th digit differs and that, because of that, it is marked as a difference.

I have no idea on how to solve this. Is Excel somewhere rounding automatically in the SUM IF function?

[image]

Comment: If you don't need 14 decimal places of accuracy then use a rounding formula tondo the comparison. Eg ROUND

Answer (score 0):

You left out a lot of information but my wild guess is that you might have missed absolute referencing.

If I assume that your data is in columns `A` and `B` you your aggregation is in columns `D` and `E` this is what your formula in `D2` should look like:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,D2,B:B)
```

or

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$13,D2,$B$1:$B$13)
```

As for the conditional, assuming your sums are in `E7` and `F7`, I hope you use:

```
=$E$7<>$F$7
```

Comment: I'm familiar with relative/absolute referencing. The range is the same, formulas with the $ marks :)

Comment: Okay, so can you share your formulas?

Comment: Sure:

=SUMIF($D$100:$D$10178;"NE";$K$100:$K$10178)  for the SUM IF
=SUM($K$20:$K$25) to sum the SUM IF
=$K$26<>SUM($K$100:$K$1492) for the conditional formatting

Comment: Why do you go to row 10178 with `SIMIF()` and only 1492 rows for `SUM()`?

Comment: Both are empty... Just in some sheets we have more rows but indeed a valid point :) Point is that I use the same values but get a different result (only when I check until the 14th digit) :)